# In React Native to handle Three-finger screenshot of OnePlusthreeT

Tags: android, react-native, screenshot, oneplusthree

In React Native to handle Three-finger screenshot of OnePlusthree and OnePlusThreeT is going for a Crash

[image]

This Error Occurs in Debug build while Three-finger screenshot gesture

[image]

Note : 
1. Remote Debugging is not enabled. 
2. In Signed Play Store Build there is no problem, Screenshot is taking successfully. Only in Debug build facing this issue.

Can we handle this programatically ?

Comment: Have you narrowed down where this error is coming from in Java?

Comment: This is an open issus  in Github [reactnative](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15059). it happens in dubug mode not in relese mode.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Put this in app.js or root file of your app. This worked for me.

```
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;
```